# Property 'description' does not exist on type '{ label: string; value: string; }'

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, response

I want to sort my `response.data` but have this error:

> Property 'description' does not exist on type '{ label: string;
> value: string; }'.

```
 getItemsTypes(): Observable<OptionModel[]> {
    const url = ApiUrlsConfig.risks.getItemsTypes();
    return this.http.get<ResponseModel<ItemsType[]>>(url).pipe(
      map((response) =>
        response.data.map((c) => ({
          label: c.description,
          value: c.id
        })).sort((a, b) => a.description > b.description ? 1 : -1))
    );
  }
```

Any idea please? How to fix this error?

Comment: your array doesn't have ```description``` property is has only ```label``` and ```value``` that's why you are getting error. On what basis you would like to sort your array?

Answer (score 1):

Your array doesn't have `description` property is has only `label` and `value` property that's why you are getting error.

In `sort(a,b)` function `a` and `b` refer to array elements.

I think you want to sort based on your description length. And you are assigning `description` inside `label`. So you can do like this

```
    const url = ApiUrlsConfig.risks.getItemsTypes();
    return this.http.get<ResponseModel<ItemsType[]>>(url).pipe(
      map((response) =>
        response.data.map((c) => ({
          label: c.description,
          value: c.id
        })).sort((a, b) => a.label - b.label))
    );
  }
```

Comment: I want to sort them alphabetically. Thanks